# What's the difference between I2CDevice.CreateReadTransaction() and new I2CDevice.I2CReadTransaction()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework, i2c

I'm looking into the .NET MF I2C API, and I'm getting a bit confused. There seem to be multiple ways to create an I2C transaction.

I can either use the [I2CDevice.CreateReadTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee432174.aspx) method, or simply create a new [I2CDevice.I2CReadTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee434124.aspx) object. I'm puzzled as to what the difference is. Both take the same number of arguments.

Comment: For starters, the one is Read the other is Write.

Answer (score 0):

The CreateReadTransaction returns a I2CReadTransaction object. So the difference is that the CreateReadTransaction is a method and the other is a class object.

Comment: What? `new I2CDevice.I2CReadTransaction(buffer)` returns a new `I2CReadTransaction` as well, doesn't it? So why would I use `I2CDevice.CreateReadTransaction(buffer)`?